# accessing zustand updated state from function is returning initial state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, react-state, zustand

Here, I am making an API call that set the state of setActiveIds

```
const {
        data: lastVisitedPage,
        isLoading: lastPageLoading,
        isError: lastPageIsError,
        error: lastPageError,
        isSuccess: lastPageSuccess,
      } = useQuery(
        ["lastVisitedPage"],
        async () => getLastVisitedPageFn(bookId, subjectId)
      );
    useEBookStore.getState().setActiveIds(data.id,data.chapterId);
```

Here is the Zustand store.

```
export const useEBookStore = create()(
  persist(
    (set, get) => ({
      activePageId: "",
      activeChapterId:"",
      setActiveIds: (pageId, sectionId) =>
        set({
          activePageId: pageId,
          activeChapterId: sectionId,
        }),
))
```

I have another component that will make a call to two different actions on the button trigger.

```
const View = () => {
  const { refetchChapterPages, refetchPagesHtml } = useChapterAndPagesHtml();
  const changePage = async () => {
     onNavigateNextPage();
  };
  const changePreviousPage = async () => {
     onNavigatePreviousPage();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => changePreviousPage()}> previous</button>
      <button onClick={() => changePage()}> next</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default View;
```

other two actions that will update the setActiveIds state and access its value

```
export const onNavigateNextPage = async () => {
const activeId = useEBookStore.getState().activePageId;
    useEBookStore.getState().setActiveIds("123",5);
};

export const onNavigatePreviousPage = async () => {
const activeId = useEBookStore.getState().activePageId;
    useEBookStore.getState().setActiveIds("123",5);

};
```

In the above code when I click on the next button it is successfully updating the activePageId value from the onNavigateNextPage action but when I click on the previous button and try to access the updated state of the activePageId value from the onNavigatePreviousPage action it is always returning initial state value i.e. ' '

Answer (score 0):

Everything you use inside the queryFn needs to be part of the queryKey:

```
useQuery(
- ["lastVisitedPage"],
+ ["lastVisitedPage", bookId, subjectId],
  async () => getLastVisitedPageFn(bookId, subjectId)
)
```